# background-img property not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to set an image as a background but it's not working and I am not getting anything in the background.  Can you guys see my code and tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Here's my CSS code:

```css
#card1 {
  background-image: url(https://eiwgew27fhz.exactdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/hero-4.jpg?strip=all&lossy=1&sharp=1&fit=1024%2C1024&ssl=1);
}
```

Here's my HTML code:

```HTML
<div class="card" id="card1"></div>
<div class="card" id="card2"></div>
<div class="card" id="card3"></div>
```

I am trying to apply different images on all of these boxes with the help of Id using image address.

Comment: this is because your div is `0 x 0` pixels size.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#card1 {
  background-image: url(https://eiwgew27fhz.exactdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/hero-4.jpg?strip=all&lossy=1&sharp=1&fit=1024%2C1024&ssl=1);
}

#card2 {
  background-image: url(https://eiwgew27fhz.exactdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/hero-4.jpg?strip=all&lossy=1&sharp=1&fit=1024%2C1024&ssl=1);
}

#card3 {
  background-image: url(https://eiwgew27fhz.exactdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/hero-4.jpg?strip=all&lossy=1&sharp=1&fit=1024%2C1024&ssl=1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card" id="card1"></div>
  <div class="card" id="card2"></div>
  <div class="card" id="card3"></div>
</body>
```